# Two particulat tags in the same line

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I am wondering if something like that is possible to achieve with Java JAXB library:

```
  <test>
        <row>
             <en>value <same>val2</same>
             </en>               
        </row>
                ...
  </test>
```

And Java code, from which the xml should be generated:

```
class Test{

@XmlElement
List<Row> rows;

}

class Row{

@XmlElement
En en;

}

class En{

@XmlElement
Same same;

}

class Same{

List<String> value;

}
```

What I am asking is to have the `same` tag in the same line as `en` tag. And all the other tags should be auto indented in new line.
Thank you

Comment: same and en tag refer to which library or language ?

Comment: @gowridev `same` and `en` tags are just xml tags mapped from Java class. I edited the post and added some Java code too.

Answer (score 0):

please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402212/how-do-i-make-xsl-transformation-indent-the-output). Workaround approach would be do post-processing of indented xml file.